# Cause of java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.Native.register(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tess4j

I have a java aplication and I´m moving to dynamic web projet.

The desktop application works fine, but in the dynamic web project I´m getting this error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.Native.register(Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1.<clinit>(TessAPI1.java:44)
```

The line 44 in the `TessAPI1` library is

`Native.register(WINDOWS ? LIB_NAME : LIB_NAME_NON_WIN);`

what is the possible cause of this error?

Comment: Are you sure there is a method `register` in that `native` class?

Comment: I´m not sure, I can´t see the source code of that class, Native is a dot class file

Comment: Are the JARs fully loaded in the project? It seems that the one containing the method is missing.

Comment: are 2 dll files and I´m loading using the absolute path using system.load(). another method use some of the features of those jars and works fine, in the web version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of your interface is not present or is not at the correct version. Update the implementation version where it has that method implemented.

Comment: I´m not sure if Im understanding, what do you mean.  this is my code http://pastie.org/9524189, I´m think  if the interface is not present the desktop java aplication should not work

Comment: Yes but there need to be an implementation of that interface. I won't give you an error till you call a method of that interface.
In your case com.sun.jna.Native.register is the interface. 
Most likely this should be its implementation net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1 check the version of this jar if it is the latest or not...

Comment: I´m using maven and i have this 
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
Is the unique version in the maven repository

Comment: what is the API version ?
Did you just update the version or add it right now ?

Comment: In the Test API1.class I found this coment 
/**
 * A Java wrapper for <code>Tesseract OCR 3.02 API</code> using
 * <code>JNA Direct Mapping</code>.
 */
And this is the full error trace http://pastie.org/9524220

Comment: update your version to 2.0 beta and try ... Think it should solve your problem ... also make sure your manifest is generated correctly. I would suggest you to delete it and do a mvm clean install on the project...

Comment: The version of Tess4j ? I just found the 1.3 i searched here http://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/ and http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j

Comment: Man i moved all to the new version, actually not using maven, all the java files imported to the project, but I have the same error.

Comment: Man but im usign the vesion 2 beta that you said, I dont know what lastest version do you mean

Comment: error jar has changed ... com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60558/discussion-between-aeshang-and-juan-camilo-mejia).

Comment: I solved the problem, I delete the dependency from maven instead that i added the jars manually to the build path  and I added the jars in a folder named lib inside WEB-INF, (I created that folder beacause is not by default in the project) again thanks for your time @wrongAnswer

Comment: welcome if i pointed you in the right direction please mark this as an answer so it can help some one else.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class NoSuchMethodError
    extends IncompatibleClassChangeError
```

Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.

Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

Comment: I´m think if the method  is not present, the desktop java aplication should not work. or are differents names definitions?

Comment: Yeah, it compile, but when the jvm went to look for that method it didnt  it find it. Take a look at classDefnotfoundexception vs classnotfoundexception

Comment: Ok, but the desktop version actually works not just compile. I read the post, so are you thinking that is a classpath problem?